# Core Bluetooth: Issue when writing value to peripheral

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I set LED color in my peripheral in the following way:

```
let data = Data(bytes: [0x10, 0x10, 0x10])
self.sensorTagAsCentral!.writeValue(data, for: self.colorCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
```

its behaviour is absolutely chaotic and undeterministic, sometimes it works just fine and changes the LED color, sometimes it does not change anything and prints the following warning in console

```
WARNING: <private> is not a valid characteristic for peripheral <private>
```

Since it occurrs ocasionally, it's hard to debug and solve it.

Anybody experience such issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: when it happen, fresh connection or device is already connected?

Comment: when device is already connected @rohitSidpara

Comment: Same issue here. Any solutions?